# Branching process where R is less than 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a Galton-Watson Process with offspring distribution $(d_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and $R < 1$.
Let $P(S_n)$ be the probability that the population survived until the $n$-th generation.
Using the Markov Inequality one can proof that $s_n:=P(S_n)\leq R^n$

Markov Inequality:
Let $X$ be a random variable and $E[|X|]<\infty, a>0$, then
$P(|X|\geq a)\leq \frac{E{|X|}}{a}$

What I tried:
Let $a=1$, then the Markov Inequality yields $P(S_n\geq1)\leq R$, taking this to the $n$-th power the result follow. Now I am not really sure if it is really that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_n$ be the number of individuals in the $n$ generation. The expectation of $Z_n$ is $R^n$. Now, by Markov, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z_n\geq 1] \leq \mathbb{Z_n} = R^n.$$
The event $Z_n\geq 1$ is exactly the event that the population survives to at least the $n$th generation.